# How do I pull the "At this location" info from the google maps api?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

for example... 1130 Racquet Club North Drive Indianapolis IN 46260

has both a tennis court and an apartment complex.. tried the places api, but none of them seem to return what I see on the map at that location. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reserve geocoding?

Answer (score 0):

This code example.

I hope this code helps you

```
let lat;
    let long;
    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        //alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var latitud= document.getElementById('latitud');
        lat = latitud.value = position.coords.latitude
        var longitud= document.getElementById('longitud');
        long = longitud.value = position.coords.longitude
    }
```

Comment: I can get the latitude and longitude using Google's geocode api and I'm trying to use the places api to get what's located at that address.. Trying to use the PlaceDetails api but so far no luck.. i get nothing back..

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.